# Missing KVM snapshots in virt-manager

Tags: libvirt, qemu, virsh, virt-manager, libvirt-guests

I need to resize an image and receive an error when using `qemu-img` the resize is not supported because snapshots exist. Sure enough, even though `virt-manager` does not show any snapshots, I see the following  when listing the snapshots with `qemu-img`:

```
[root@nebula216-1 ~]# qemu-img snapshot -l /vm_images/valuelynk-www.img
Snapshot list:
ID        TAG                 VM SIZE                DATE       VM CLOCK
1         snapshot1                 0 2017-12-20 00:47:40   00:00:00.000
2         pre-upgrade-freebsd11   2.0G 2018-05-19 14:58:50  165:51:36.706
3         freebsd11-mysqlsslrepl      0 2018-05-20 12:18:42   21:07:22.606
```

The problem is, this VM has two disks and both show these same snapshots. How can I get `virt-manager` in sync or safely delete all snapshots so I can resize the image?

Answer (score 1):

It seems using `qemu-img` to remove all snapshots from both disks works just fine. At least on a test server, I was able to do the following for all three snapshots on both images:

```
qemu-img snapshot -d $SNAPSHOT_NAME $DISK_IMAGE
```

Afterward, the `qemu-img resize` worked without issue.